ngrok gateway error The server returned an invalid or incomplete HTTP response. (ERR_NGROK_3004) with docker container
I use docker for my TelegramBot, it is listening ports 5141:5140, if I try to use ngrok for public https address, i get error 3004 from ngrok. Can I use ngrok with my docker compose project or I need to add nrok to docker compose? I just don't know what I can do with it
I tried to use different ports (5141&5140), use network_mode: "bridge", rewrite etc. I just need ngrok to map my localhost to https public address

I have a suggestion and a question. The question is, are you able get the proper response on localhost without using ngrok?
Also, you can you ngrok in docker compose. The entry would look something like this:
services:
  ngrok:
      image: ngrok/ngrok:latest
      command: 
        - "http" 
        - "http://host.docker.internal:<your-port>" 
        - "--domain=<your-domain>"
      environment:
        NGROK_AUTHTOKEN: ${NGROK_AUTHTOKEN}
      ports:
        - "5141:5140"


I can't get response on localhost without ngrok because I use telegram bot webhook and, as I know, I need public address to get it.
i tried
  gamebottest:
    image: gamebottest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: GameBotTest/Dockerfile
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "5141:5140"
  ngrok:
    image: ngrok/ngrok:latest
    command: http 5140
    environment:
      NGROK_AUTHTOKEN:
    ports:
      - "4040:4040"```
But now i have "Traffic was tunneled ... failed to establish a connection to web service at localhost:5140. (ERR_NGROK_8012)"

Ah. My bad. For the command field you need to list out the entire docker internal URL http://host.docker.internal:<your-port>  for the port. I updated my answer to reflect that. I also reformatted it to fit in the window.

tried this and still have Traffic was successfully tunneled to the ngrok agent, but the agent failed to establish a connection to the upstream web service at gamebottest:5141. (ERR_NGROK_8012)

I think we're close. Rather than using gamebottest:5141, you would use http://host.docker.internal:5141. Here's a Gist that better explains what I'm talking about. https://gist.github.com/stmcallister/c087ea1640d59f101172b7682f42d7b1
